# VS Code Google debugger unverified breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have been using Google debugger in VS Code for a long time, but all of a sudden, I downloaded one sample project and all of my breakpoints are after app start immediately evaluated as unverified. I cannot find out why.

Project itself works smoothly, I only have this problem when I want to debug.

See the picture:

[image]

Please, does anybody have idea what can cause it? I guess this might be related to there is no SRC folder and everything is inside PUBLIC folder.

launch.json

```
{  
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project Two: Timers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./semantic-dist/semantic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="vendor/babel-standalone.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/react.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/uuid.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/fetch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" class="main ui">
    <h1 class="ui dividing centered header">Timers</h1>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/babel" src="./js/client.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel" src="./js/helpers.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-class-properties" src="./js/app-complete.js"></script>
  <!-- Delete the script tag below to get started. -->
  <!-- <script type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-class-properties" src="./js/app.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```